# swift combinations for dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, combinations

Before I was using this version of combinations func:

```
func combinationsT<T>(of array: [[T]]) -> [[T]] {
    return array.reduce([[]]) {
        var x = [[T]]()
        for i in $0 {
            for j in $1 {
                x.append(i + [j])
            }
        }
        return x
    }
}

var p1 = [[1,2,3],[0,1]]
var c1 = combinationsT(of: p1)
print(c1)
```

Output is `[[1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 0], [3, 1]]`

Now I want to change it to work with Dictionary, but have some problems:

```
func combinations(of parList: [String : [Any]]) -> [String : [Any]] {
    return parList.reduce([:]) {
        var x = [String : [Any]]()

        for i in $0 {
            for j in $1.value {
                //x.updateValue(i + [j], forKey: $1.key)
            }
        }

        return x
    }
}

var p2 = [String : [Any]]()
p2.updateValue([1,2,3], forKey: "period")
p2.updateValue([0,1], forKey: "type")
var c2 = combinations(of: p2)
print(c2)
```

The output should be `[["period" : 1, "type" : 0], ..., ["period" : 3, "type" : 1]]`

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: and you are expecting `[[String : Any]]` but function is returning `[String : [Any]]` ??

Comment: Yes, that’s probably a mistake: func should take [String : [Any]] and return [[String : Any]].

Comment: updateValue does work!